# Adjust third person view when inside a workshop area

Tags: fallout-4

You can hold down back/select and adjust the field of view variably.

When you are inside a workshop area however, holding back/select becomes our trigger for the workshop menu - meaning we can't adjust the third person's view anymore.

Is there another way of varying the third person field of view whilst in a workshop area?

Comment: I don't think there is... I'm speaking from a PS4 point of view, but the back/select functionality is identical to the dualshock's touchpad. I have not found a way to use it while inside a workshop...

Comment: The only way I found is to quickly adjust your field of view in short intervals. It's a huge pain, but it's the only way I found that works.

Answer (score 1):

I was still able to adjust the field of view using the same method as normal.
There appears to be two "holding intervals" which give you two different functionalities. This was tested on my PS4 last night but I see no reason why it should not apply to XBox or PC:

1. Holding back/select/touchpad and **immediately** attempting to adjust the view seems to work as normal.
2. Holding the same button for more than a couple seconds opens workshop mode and does not allow the adjustment of view.

Summary: As long as you don't have a pause between holding back/select/touchpad and adjusting your view, you should have some level of success. Now, I did not check if the workshop forces itself open if you take "too long" adjusting your view...

Comment: I was under the impression you could only adjust the view *while* holding down the button. Are you adjusting it super-quick and releasing it, or are you implying you can hold it for just a moment, release, and still adjust after it is released?

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's a bit annoying having to repeat the process a few times to get a full view

Comment: @DCShannon, adjusting super quick and releasing, before workshop mode has a chance to open.

Comment: It forces itself open if you take too long. I can't switch my view fast enough for it to be worth even trying. That's annoying, as I like to position my camera for a nice picture before saving.